# What .BAT command to use to eject a USB drive (dismount, remove - you pick the proper verb)

Tags: batch-file, cmd, usb

From a .BAT file, how do you eject a USB drive knowing the drive letter, e.g. trying to eject e:

```
@echo off
rem What is this command?
EJECT e:
if errorlevel 1 goto could_not_eject
  echo Success!
  goto end
:could_not_eject
  echo Unable to eject e:
  goto end
:end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [ejectjs.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/ejectjs.bat) :

```
::to eject specific dive by letter
call ejectjs.bat G
::to eject all drives that can be ejected
call ejectjs.bat *
```

There's no built-in command that can do this.

You can try also with powershell (it didn't worked for me):

powershell and the [wmi class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/vdswmi/dismount-method-in-class-win32-volume?redirectedfrom=MSDN):

```
powershell "(get-wmiobject -Class Win32_Volume | where{$_.DriveLetter -eq 'G:'}).Dismount($true,$false)"
```

or the wmic command :

```
wmic path Win32_Volume where DriveLetter="G:" call Dismount
```

it didn't worked for me. You can also use wmi classes through jscript but I haven't try it. Looks like only invoke verb solution works without problems.

Comment: So there's definitely no built-in command?  That's my question.  I know I can write code to do it, but I was hoping I could do it in a .BAT file with a built-in command.  :-\

Comment: BTW, I have NOT verified that the "ejectjs.bat" works.  _I only accepted the answer of_ **There's no built-in command that can do this**.

Comment: @franji1 - hmm.. I'm still looking on this. I'm close to brew a wmic command with  Win32_Volume class.

Comment: @franji1 - I've updated my answer. If you want to enhance this or write it in different language you at least have some kind of refference.

Comment: `wmic path Win32_Volume where (DriveLetter like '%' and DriveType=2) call Dismount` (double the `%`-sign in a batch file)? this would regard only removable disks and exclude such without a dedicated drive letter...

Comment: @aschipfl - thanks (type 5 is also dismountable). Turned out there's a difference between eject and dismount. This will not eject the CD drive for example.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for windows 10 with admin rights:

```
mountvol <drive> /d
```

Comment: I don't think this just does an "eject".  If I attempt to reinsert the USB drive, it no longer shows up.

Comment: I had to re-mount it using the mountvol command.  It literally removed that "mount point" from the system (hence the admin requirement).  I just want to "eject", which should not require admin.  Key issue is that that volume could not be recognized again.

Comment: @franji Ok, understand, like a DVD drive eject

Comment: Sadly, I do not know what the proper "action" term is.  The Windows GUI uses the term "Eject" verb for a USB drive, like a DVD MECHANICAL "eject".  Basically, you right click on a USB drive (or a DVD drive), and the verb Eject shows up for both.  For USB flash drives, it flushes the cache to the flash media and makes it removable.  I am only guessing about "dismount" or "remove" or ???